# When connected to proxy networks, Grafana does not display the dashboards for Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, health-monitoring

While choosing the data source for ElasticSearch,I see a direct connect option or connect it via proxy whereas it is not present for Cloudwatch. When connected to proxy networks, Grafana does not display the dashboards. Tried setting proxy for windows in custom.ini file but it doesnt help. Request for a solution.

Please include this information:

What Grafana version are you using?
Grafana 4.3.1
What datasource are you using?
CloudWatch
What OS are you running grafana on?
Windows7
What did you do?
Tried setting proxy in custom.ini file

Answer (score 0):

The direct/proxy setting defines whether connections to the data source should be made "direct" from the browser (requiring proper CORS setup, etc) or whether to "proxy" them through the Grafana server.

If you need Grafana to use an HTTP(S) proxy for connections made by the Grafana server, then you need to set the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyIp:proxyPort"` and Grafana (as well as any other programs using the standard golang http libraries) will use the defined proxy.

Comment: Where do I define this proxy. Tried in custom.ini but no luck.

Comment: You need to set an environment variable, on Windows 7 you can follow these instructions: https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500